# Display unique values in dropdown list from dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dataset table with rows and columns extracted. I want to display one of the column values( Dates) from the dataset in a dropdown list. Here is the code i have written for filling dates into drop down list. The problem is there are similar dates, I want unique dates to be filled..

```
Public void fillDates()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds = bal.selectDateOfTest(qstrng);
    ddlTestDate.Items.Clear();
    ddlTestDate.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        ddlTestDate.Items.Add(new ListItem(
        Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0]).Trim(), 
        Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0])));
}
```

Comment: The T-SQL syntax to group by dates (if, for example, your column is "datetime") is something like this: [T-SQL select where and group by date](http://geekswithblogs.net/bconlon/archive/2011/02/21/t-sql-select-where-and-group-by-date.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adapt your query that returns all dates to group the dates, this would be the best approach.

Alternatively, you could implement code that does the grouping after it has been returned from the database.

Answer (score 0):

make a query that returns only unique  date that is:

```
select distinct Dates from yourtable
```

your sql query  will be called by your selectDateOfTest method

Answer (score 0):

Try using this query to get the datatable to have the unique column values:
DataTable uniqueTable = results.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Dates");

Where **results** is the name of your data table.